# Centering a polygon on the origin by affine translation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

Given a set of tuples, each representing the vertices of a polygon, I would like to center it on the origin. Having calculated the centermost point of the polygon (not the arithmetic centroid) and the distance between it and the origin, how would I go about translating it?

Could I just apply an affine homogeneous translation on the point set\begin{bmatrix}1&0&dx\\0&1&dy \\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

where $dx$ and $dy$ are the distance to the origin? I have a sneaking suspicion that this will not suffice.

Comment: It actually _will_ work just fine.

Comment: If your "centermost point" has coordinates $(a,b)$, then all you have to do is subtract $(a,b)$ from each of your vertices.

Comment: Are you still here, Tom?

Comment: Thanks! Both approaches seem to work just fine, although, without testing, I cannot say which will be most computationally efficient.